# wp 8.1 usercontrol and OxyPlot not showing up

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, oxyplot

I have a usercontrol with grid as content panel, which loads its content from datatemplate, specified in xaml where usercontrol is used.

I am using this usercontrol widely and everything is fine with standard xaml controls in template.
now I am trying to show some charts in this control with OxyPlot

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeChart">
        <Grid x:Name="oxyGrid" >
            <oxy:PlotView x:Name="oxyChart" Model="{Binding model}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I initialize data model for the chart in usercontrol_loaded
but the chart will not be shown until I manually call InvalidateMeasure for it.
if I call invalidatemeasure from usercontrol_loaded , it will not help.

if I call invalidatemeasure from any point when chart is on the screen - it helps and chart will shows up.

currently, I found that I can call invalidatemeasure in usercontrol_layoutupdated handler but don't like as it fires too often
and requires code outside of usercontrol.

if I try to handle event layoutupdated inside usercontrol and call invalidatemeasure (for oxychart) from there, I am getting "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete."

any ideas about what's wrong and how to fix :)
will be greatly appreciated
thanks in advance
ilya

Answer (score 0):

never hurry to post questions :)

just necessary to call UpdateLayout() in usercontrol after loading template

```
   private void spContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTemplate();
        UpdateLayout();
    }
```

where spContentPanel is just Grid for template loading

```
   <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="spContentPanel" Loaded="spContentPanel_Loaded"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    </Grid>
```